# Trouble making Gobos

Tags: lighting, shader-nodes

Pretty new to Blender as well as this forum. I've been following a few tutorials to learn how to make gobos (dark plate in front of light source) but whatever the method being used, I can't get them to work.

I've tried making them within the light source with geometry nodes with different setups but nothing showed up. Then I tried making a plane with transparent BSDF and it's barely working.
I tries pngs as well as tiff files

I've watched a certain number of tutorials each doing very similar stuff and checked how they connected their nodes but I can't seem to reproduce their results.

There must be something off in my render settings or something but I can't figure it out. (I am using cycles for the shader nodes to work and haven't changed too many settings otherwise)

Here is my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8zHuuUh5J2qnTCMnXLKcwdZBQeezfQH/view?usp=sharing